# Qt on OS X building a 10.5 compatible application on 10.6

Tags: macos, qt

I'm running Mac OS X 10.6 on my development machine and am building a QT application that I would like to work on 10.5 (and 10.4) as well as 10.6. My application has both a library component and a gui component, each as their own QT project with dependencies.

I have followed the instructions of the QT deployment guide. In both .pro files I have added:

```
CONFIG += x86 ppc
QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.4
```

I peered inside the makefile, and confirmed that it includes a line `export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.4`

I built QT static with the following configure:
`./configure -universal -sdk /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/ -opensource -static -debug-and-release`

I compiled my application in QT Creator, and the resultant application runs flawlessly on 10.6 machines, but crashes on 10.5 machines.

**Is there anything else I need to be doing to get a QT application working on OS X 10.5? Does anyone have any idea why this is crashing?**

```
Process:         MyApp[25908]
Path:            /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
Identifier:      MyApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [109]

Interval Since Last Report:          17392106 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           735
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  0 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   8

Date/Time:       2010-08-14 07:50:09.768 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.5.8 (9L31a)
Report Version:  6
Anonymous UUID:  1BF30470-ACF2-46C7-B6D5-4514380965C8

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: __ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_i
  Referenced from: /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
```

Comment: `export MACOSZX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.4`  Is that a typo?  It should undoubtedly be `export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.4`

Comment: @Ned Deily I wish the answer were so easy, but unfortunately, that was a typo in my manually copying it over from my dev machine.

Comment: Google shows quite a lot of people reporting a similar error on the same missing symbol in many different software projects. It looks like something dragged in when building on 10.6, possibly dependent on how/what got linked in on 10.6.
There's a previous Stackoverflow question on the same symbol

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484043/os-x-program-runs-on-dev-machine-crashing-horribly-on-others

Comment: any reason why you combine 10.4 (deployment target) and sdk 10.5 (configure flag)? I'd try with both being consistent. Maybe 10.5 first, then 10.4.

Comment: also, the ostream_insert header (where this seem to come from?) only exists in my 10.6 SDK, and only for gcc 4.2.1, not 4.0.0

Comment: So sounds like something is linked against the 10.6 SDK. Time for otool, lipo or ldd - or this GUI tool http://code.google.com/p/macdependency/

Comment: @Frank I combined 10.4 deployment target with the 10.5 SDK because I thought that's the way you target 10.4 on Snow Leopard? They removed the 10.4 SDK from Snow Leopard, and there's only 10.6 and 10.5 now. That said, good idea, I will give it a try to change it to 10.5 as the deployment target.